# SQL Procedure to find if an input is an invalid input

Tags: sql, procedure

```
CREATE OR REPLACE
PROCEDURE CONDITIONPROCEDURE(INPUT CONDITION CCONDITION.CONDITION%TYPE )
as 
C.NAME%TYPE
CC.CONDITION%TYPE

BEGIN 
SELECT NAME, CONDITION 
INTO C_NAME, CC_CONDITION
FROM CLIENT, CCONDITION
WHERE CC_CONDITION = 'acrophobia'

DMBS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('CLIENT HAS ACROPHOBIA OR HEART CONDITION)
```

so far my code looks like this but I am unsure if this is on the right track to answering my question;

the question being "Write a stored procedure that displays the contact details of clients who does not have any heart conditions or Acrophobia."

The table references appear as

```
   CLIENT (ClientNo, Name, Sex, DOB, Address, Phone, Email, Occupation,
   MaritalStatus, Spouse, Anniversary)
   CCONDITION (ClientNo, Condition)
```

I Am only just learning SQL so any advice / readings would be much appreciated.

Comment: Tag the dbms you're using. (That code seems to be product specific.)

Answer (score 0):

First you need proper query which will select clients with no 'acrophobia' or 'heart condition' detected. NOT EXISTS (correlated subquery) is the right tool here

```
SELECT NAME, CONDITION 
FROM CLIENT c 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT 1 
      FROM CCONDITION cond
      WHERE cond.ClientNo = c.ClientNo
           AND cond.CC_CONDITION IN ( 'acrophobia', 'heart condition'))
```

Next step is wrap this query into procedure which is DBMS specific and  also DBMSes have a number of options for what should the proc return. For example, you may want to return refcursor or alternatively create [Pipelined Table Function](http://psoug.org/reference/pipelined.html) in Oracle.